# What are operating-system personalities?

Tags: operating-system, kernel

Section 2.7.5 (page 83) of [Operating System Concepts Essentials, 2nd Edition](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Operating+System+Concepts+Essentials%2C+2nd+Edition-p-9781118804926) says (emphasis in original):

> Windows is largely monolithic as well (again primarily for performance reasons), but it retains some behavior typical of microkernel systems, including providing support for separate subsystems (known as operating-system ***personalities***) that run as user-mode processes.

Googling turns up a bunch of irrelevant online quizzes, but also [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_kernel), which mentions the term several times but doesn't appear to give a definition. Is this a standard term? What is a definition distinguishing it from other similar terms (e.g. "subsystems" from the above quote)?

Comment: I puzzled how that book remains in use. Most people who are confused by an OS book who post here are confused by that book. It's not a standard term.

Answer (score 0):

Personalities were very much a thing in early 90s OS designs and implementations.   That books has mashed the concept of services and personalities to a poor effect.  I hazard that it is quite wrong.

The POSIX personality is probably the most important one of the dos/windows line.   At least, the only way I've ever used windows is in a posix shell, so just another unix.   The earlier versions of Win/NT, VMS from DEC, also had a unix as a subsystem variant.

At the time, USENIX other architectures was brimming with various OSes that ran binaries and environments from other OSes, which was quite fascinating.  PinkOS, or Taligent, aimed to bring multi-personality-disorder to desktop operating systems.   But it promised a lot.  Truth was, once you got beyond a few basic utilities, most approaches ran out of steam.

Then came Java, which effectively turned it all into a beige mush.

Readily available desktop virtualization was pretty much the end of the personality craze.